# How to add insert a value into a picker in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, picker

I am looking for a way to insert an "empty" value into a picker which retrieves its data from a store. The value should be added before any other value returned from the store. I tried to override the "getRange" method like this:

```
Ext.define('UK.store.Locations', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'
    ],

    config: {
        model: 'UK.model.Location',
        autoLoad: true,

        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            limitParam: false,
            startParam: false,
            url: 'http://my.url.com/locations.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'location'
            }
        }
    },

    getRange : function(startIndex, endIndex) {
        var records = this.callParent(startIndex, endIndex);
        var empty = Ext.create('UK.model.Location', 'All');
        records.unshift(empty);
        return records;
    }

});
```

But the value is always displayed at the end of the picker data. Is there any other way to do it, maybe by overriding some picker methods?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` config of the data store and add one empty "" record to the array. So, this data will be already added to the store and the next set will be appended to it.

You can also use `setData()` function of store and add one extra record. And then load the store instead of autoloading.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work the way you suggested. If I just set the data: property in the store, it will always be overwritten. Overriding the setData function also does not work because its not called by the picker. I tried to overwrite the load method of the store but could not insert any value to the data collection returned by the store's getData() method..

Comment: Then you can just use an Ajax request, get the data and then use setData function to load data. This way you can add the empty data at first and then can set other data.

Comment: This could work but its strange that such a simple task can not be achieved easier..